# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 - WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress

I migrated a wordpress website to a new host, i made some edit to the wordpress page and tried to save the page. It was giving me the error below when i used google chrome console to debug the issue

```
“Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()”

with the route “wp-admin/admin-ajax.php:1”
```

After trying all the solutions outlined below, so i was able to fix it by using the **Solution 6**.

Answer (score 0):

403 forbidden means that your browser isn’t able to load the scripts up because your server isn’t allowing it. This is a hard one to solve. Because anything could be blocking the server. Hence 403 forbidden error is very vague, the error log may give you clue.

**Solution 1** – Most likely this is a server permissions/ownership issue. If its a permission issue, it may tell you which file has incorrect permissions, so ask your host what’s going on. If you are using cPanel, the following tutorial has more information about the error log in cPane: How to view cPanel Error logs

**Solution 2** – If the problem is file permissions, you can follow the steps in the below article to learn how to modify your file permissions: How to change file permissions within cPanel https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

**Solution 3** – Another possible cause could be a corrupt .htaccess file. Also check your .htaccess files for anything strange.

**Solution 4** –  make sure your server settings are not overriding the .htaccess file.

**Solution 5** –  Another possible cause could be changes to the server settings (accidental or otherwise). Check with your hosting provider.

**Solution 6** -Last but not the least solution, disable mod security for that domain.